# How can i get x indexed row from a table in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, plsql

First of all feel free to correct my English and
I have just started PL/SQL.

Here is my PL/SQL code.
There is table called 'EMP' with employees's information.

My goal is to get the median of the employees's wage.
So if the number of employees is odd then i need the middle one.

If it is even then i need the two mid ones's average.

It does the job so far, im just confused after the "if" statement.
What is the easiest way to get the nth indexed row's value?

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

DECLARE
    counter Int(4);
    osszeg Int(5);
    temp EMP.sal%TYPE;

CURSOR wage IS
  SELECT EMP.SAL
  FROM EMP
  ORDER BY EMP.SAL ASC;  


BEGIN    
     OPEN wage;
     counter := 0;

LOOP
  FETCH wage
  INTO temp;
  EXIT WHEN wage%NOTFOUND;
  counter := counter + 1;    
END LOOP;    
CLOSE wage;
```

AND i need help from here

```
IF MOD(counter,2) = 0 THEN

ELSE


END IF;

END;
```

Comment: Before learning PLSQL, understand that in RDBMS a table is an unordered set of rows. There is no first/middle/nth/last row unless you specify a proper order.

Comment: I know it sorry, i forgot to sort it in ascending order.

Answer (score 1):

You can use analytic functions, it's much easier to solve your in SQL , without using PL/SQL.

```
select t.*,
       case
          when mod(totcnt, 2) = 0 then
           (Wage + LeadWage) / 2
          else
           Wage
       end
  from (select rownum RN, num, count(*) over(partition by 1) TotCnt,
                lead(Wage) over (order by Wage) LeadWage
           from Emp) t
 where t.Rn = round(TotCnt / 2);
```

or, if you  want to use PL/SQL, you should store your median value as pair of variables (current wage value and previous wage value inside you fetch operator , until you don't know is your set of wages odd or even), and while looping inside fetch use should always calculate median value in each step for previous iterations.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it easiest but not proper

```
IF MOD(counter,2) = 0 THEN
    //first_number = counter/2
    //second_number = first_number+1
    //avg= (first_number+second_number)/2

ELSE
    //first_number = counter/2;
    //avg = first_number+1

END IF;
```

Comment: I think it would just return with the average of the rows's index. Not with the rows's average value.

Comment: First of all you should order the column. 
It's also easy if you retrieve value corresponding index then calculate avg.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the median wage (sal) of all employees, then just use the MEDIAN function.

select median(sal) as median_wage from emp ;

It is available as an aggregate function and as an analytic function.